# How do I make an HDD as fast as an SSD?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, imac, ssd, hdd

I have a really slow iMac that I bought 2 years ago. I've been so annoyed about how I have to wait for the rainbow circle to stop loading. I did some research and found out it's about the hard drive. My iMac had an HDD drive. I didn't want to buy an SSD so I thought why not do something to make the HDD as fast as an SSD.

Can you please help me on making an HDD as fast as an SSD?

---

Here are my imac specs

[image]

Comment: The way to make an HDD as fast as an SSD is to tie it to a rocket and to stand back a safe distance ... but seriously, one of the avenues for pretending to boost disk access speed is to implement some kind of 'disk-in-RAM', but you don't have a lot of RAM to play with there either.  I think your best option is a hardware upgrade, you should be able to replace the HDD with an SSD.

Comment: This iMac is plenty fast. Keep the HDD for bulk storage and get the OS on faster external storage.  No need to open it, but next time it’s open, put the fastest small SSD you can afford in. 256 is plenty for any Mac if you want speed, only reason to add more is you can’t abide by external storage and you trade off money for convenience like was skipped when HDD was ordered in this Mac.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: Your rocket idea is a good start: accelerate the drive to 97% of the speed of light and let time dilation do its thing. I just can't figure out how to communicate with the drive at that speed/distance.

Comment: Have you checked your RAM usage? From my experience, a rainbow circle mostly appears on swapping which means exhausted memory. What are you running mostly when the rainbow circle appears?

Answer (score 12):

I'm afraid that's impossible. Your hard drive is essentially not much different from an old record turntable: it has spinning disks and a 'head' that writes or reads the magnetic stripe at a point on the wheel.

There are many different mechanical parts that all contribute limitations to the maximum possible speed.

Furthermore: it's a sealed unit, made in a factory. If there was some easy 'tweak' to make it as fast as an SSD, the manufacturers would have done it.

Answer (score 10):

- SSD are designed like a car. HDD are trucks.
- You can’t make a truck operate like a car unless you buy a car and call it a truck.
- Diesel fuels most trucks and some cars (computer “fuel” is SATA interface and command set).
- Most cars run gas (NVMe).

You want a light car running on gas to get the best acceleration. Boot to the fastest SSD connected via NVMe controller for max performance and speed, there is no shortcut, especially with a truck response and SATA driving.

Some HDD add a layer of SSD and try to cache data similar to how Apple does Fusion drives (think nitrous oxide), but this doesn’t get you NVMe.

In the end, connect an SSD via thunderbolt if you need equivalent speeds to having an internal SSD on an iMac. Your iMac is capable of tens of thousands of io per second if you bring fast storage to it, internally or externally so your wish can be granted, just not with HDD.

Shop for NVMe over Thunderbolt is my advice.

- https://www.macworld.com/article/3276325/nvme-over-thunderbolt-killer-external-storage-with-caveats.html

Comment: I got a Mac Mini a while back as a gift, but it had a small SSD. So I just added an external SSD via USB-C/Thunderbolt and put my users folder there. Works a treat and a lot less expensive than a new Mini with a bigger SSD. Like @bmike said you can't make a HDD into anything approaching the speed of an SDD. You could swap the HDD for an SSD or sell the Mac and buy a new one. Those are pretty much your choices.

Comment: This analogy is confusing for someone who doesn't know anything about cars.

Comment: @S.S.Anne It's also confusing to people who actually know about HDDs and SSDs.

Comment: It's a very confusing analogy. HDD is slow (125Mb/s is the usual for a laptop, up to 220Mb/s on desktop) but has lots of storage. SHDD are as fast as a SATA SSD, as long as the cache is in use. Otherwise, it's an HDD. A SATA SSD can be, in general (assuming DRAM cache), around 2-5 times faster than an HDD. An NVMe SSD can be around 2-8 times faster than a SATA SSD (even those without DRAM, assuming PCIe 4.0).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make a hard drive run as fast as an SSD, install lots of RAM, and put the system to sleep rather than shutting it down when you're finished.  If you've got enough RAM (in my experience, 64 GB is enough for a typical desktop), after a day or two of use, the parts of the disk that you normally use will be cached in memory, so the disk won't actually be accessed.

Note that it's considerably cheaper to get an SSD than it is to install enough RAM for this to work.

Comment: The [maximum RAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205040) on that machine looks like it's 32 GB, and there's no User-Installable Slot (and if you want to DIY it, the iFixit guide to get at the memory slots is 64 steps long, not counting putting the steps to put it all back together again), so this is not really practical even beside the cost.

Comment: Synchronous writes can still be a bit of a problem, when a program waits to make sure data is safely on disk before doing something else.  SSDs have orders of magnitude lower latency for that.  Other than that, yeah tons of RAM could plausibly make basically all disk accesses hit in cache or be write-buffered.

Comment: An SSD isn't going to be that much more expensive than buying a ton of extra RAM...

Comment: @PeterCordes, large synchronous writes are rare.  I've been running basically this setup for eight years, and the usual effect is a brief blip in otherwise-smooth performance.  The real performance-killer is when you do something that actually needs that 64 GB, wiping out the disk cache: you can feel the computer getting faster over the next few hours as the caches warm back up again.

Comment: @Mark: I didn't mean single a large write.  I meant if software (like a web browser) was using a database on disk for something, and was written in a way that resulted in an `fsync` or `fdatasync` after each of multiple small writes.  Or if you'd just done a bunch of small writes (e.g. database transactions), a synchronous write might have to wait for all earlier ones to drain from the disk's internal write cache, which could lead to a perceptible pause, especially if those writes were to distant locations on disk so one or two revolutions of the disk wasn't enough to write them all.

Comment: But yeah, for desktop use I'd expect no more than a brief blip.  Interactive use doesn't tend to result in lots of synchronous writes, or have lots of dirty data in flight to disk which would make one sync operation expensive.